# UIViewController as a login page with UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Ok So I am in need of a login page for my application, and once logged in will display a `UITabBar` with two tabs, one with a navigation controller, the other is a simple `UIViewController`.

At the moment, my `UITabBar` is the root controller but only want this to be shown once you have "logged in"

I want a button on my `UIViewController` which when clicked, will swap in the `UITabBar` controller.

any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `modalViewController` with `property`- username, password; with `actions` - Submit and Forgot Login and use them accordingly.

On the event that the Login is successful, `dismissModalViewController` LoginViewController and passdown the information to the AppDelegate and make the `rootViewController` (First Tab) as the viewController.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to present a full screen modal window at your app start to log in, keeping your `UITabBar` as the root controller.  Then once logged in, dismiss the modal window, showing the tabBar